# How to identify common values in two collections in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have two XML documents like below and they are in two collections

```
<Person>
  <Name>A</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
</Person>
```

another XML is like

```
<Employee>
  <EName>A</Ename>
  <ECompany>abc</ECompany>
</Employee>
```

above is the sample xmls and these two xmls are in two different collections named `person` and `employee`.  I want to identify the element `Name` from documents in the `person` collection which matches to `EName` element from documents in the `employee` collection.

Comment: How large is the dataset? Hundreds? Thousands? Millions?

Comment: Millions of data is there in the data set also there is no indexes present in the elements

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to search for the values from the `person` collection, and use them as criteria to search the `employee` collection:

```
let $person-names := cts:search(/Person/Name, cts:collection-query("person"))
return
  cts:search(/Employee/EName, 
    cts:and-query(( 
      cts:collection-query("employee"),
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("EName"), $person-names)   
    ))
  )/text()
```

However, that may not work with the scale and size of your docs.

You could use CoRB and break it into 2 phases. Run one job that returns all of the `Name` values from the docs in the `person` collection, and write it all out to a file. Then use that file as the inputs for a second job that issues a search against the `employee` collection for `EName` values, and returns the value that is written out into the final report. Same concept as above, just broken out into lots of little queries.

If you had a range-index on the `Name` and `Ename` elements, then you could use [`cts:element-values()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values), return them as a map, and find the [intersection of values](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/map-operators-use-cases/):

```
let $person-names := cts:element-values(xs:QName("Name"), "", "map", cts:collection-query("person"))
let $employee-names := cts:element-values(xs:QName("EName"), "", "map", cts:collection-query("employee"))
return $person-names * $employee-names
```